# Why UAC is not checked through ssh

Tags: uac

I am wrote a .Net Windows C# Application:

- I have add a manifest application file (Visual Studio template)
- Have changed requestedExecutionLevel to "requireAdministrator" level:

  ```
  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false">
  ```
- The application contains a basic Console.WriteLine("hello world") code.

When I run the application by double-clicking on the .exe icon, I get an UAC popup confirmation.

But if I run this application through ssh shell, I get non confirmation and the application is running ! How can I do to forbidden application to run if UAC is not confirm by user ?

Thanks

Comment: It will help you to remember that UAC isn't used to run as program as adminstrator, it is used to re-enable the administrator privileges you already have in your security token as you launch a new program. If you already are running with your administrator privileges, then there's no need to show a prompt. The program is already running as an adminstrator; not a split security token, so no UAC prompt.

Answer (score 0):

UAC prompts are actually manually launched by the program starting a new process. Windows Explorer does this, and so does cmd for example, but not necesarily any other program.

Another consideration is that a SSH server is often running as a service, and services aren't affected by UAC (by the simple fact that services have no UI at all). A remote command line would have no way to present the user a prompt so it's expectable to not to be presented one.

> How can I do to forbidden application to run if UAC is not confirm by user ?

You can't.

Administrator manifest are a **convenience** feature intended for programs explicitly looking for them, but not mandatory at all. For instance, UAC can be disabled altogether or configured to never ask, and programs may still not run with full admin access, but with whatever privileges the user has.

If your program really requires admin access to operate, be sure that your own code checks for them and exits gracefully in such case.